# How to clean corrosion from PSP analog stick connector?

Tags: psp

My PSP has been sitting in a drawer for several years and upon picking it back up the analog stick didn't work. So I went ahead and opened it up and this is what I saw:

[image]

The connector seem corroded (zoom in the image), which is strange because there's nothing wrong anywhere else.

Any ideas on how to clear/fix this?